# Remove last point from Draw Interaction in Ol3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am trying to remove the last point in a polygon draw feature on esc key.

The following code do not work. It seems to remove it when it draw the area part, but the vertex is stil there.

```
var geom :ol.geom.Polygon = null;
draw.on("drawstart",(event) => {
    console.log(event);
    var feature :ol.Feature= event.feature;
    console.log(feature);
    geom = feature.getGeometry<ol.geom.Polygon>();
});

$(document).keyup((e)=> {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        var coords = geom.getCoordinates()[0];
        if(coords.length>1)
            geom.setCoordinates([coords.slice(0, coords.length - 2)]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I have the same need too.

Comment: No, i took a different path and made such esc deleted the current drawing and the user could start over. Long term, I think I will be making a custom draw extension that fits more into our application with the options we need.

Comment: Thanks - you've taken the route I've already taken, but a user asked if I could just remove the last point, not the whole polygon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenLayers 3 has a new solution to this with the Draw.removeLastPoint() method. 
Works like a charm!

```js
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source:source,
  type: /** @type (ol.geom.GeometryType) */ ('Polygon')
})

draw.on('drawstart',
  function(evt){
    $(document).on('keyup', function(event){
      if(event.keyCode === 27){
        draw.removeLastPoint();
       }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a setCoordinates on the geometry element, after removing the last segment.

Here is an example:

```
this.olDraw.on('drawstart',
  function (evt) {
    $(document).on('keyup', function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        var feature = evt.feature;
        var geom = feature.getGeometry();
        if (geom.getType() === LINE_STRING) {
          geom.setCoordinates(geom.getCoordinates().slice(0,geom.getCoordinates().length - 1));
        }
      }
    });
  }, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is a modified version of another answer to a similar question (which I couldn't find again). Using this snippet, you can delete the last inserted point of a lineString. I think it should work for the polygon as well. give it a try.

```
var lineStringdraw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: features,
    type: "LineString",
    geometryFunction:geometryChange
});


function geometryChange(coordinates, geometry){
    if (!geometry) {
        console.info("what did you do?");
        geometry = new ol.geom.LineString(null);   
    } 
    var coords = geometry.getCoordinates();
    var diff = coordinates.length - coords.length;
    if (diff > 1) {
        coordinates.splice(coordinates.length - diff, diff - 1);
        if (coordinates.length === 1){
            lineStringdraw.finishDrawing();
            var emptyFeature = vector2.getSource().getFeatures()[vector2.getSource().getFeatures().length-1];
            vector2.getSource().removeFeature(emptyFeature);
        }
    }
    geometry.setCoordinates(coordinates);
    coordinates= geometry.getCoordinates();
    return geometry;    
}

var keydown = function(evt){
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
if (charCode === 27 && drawing === true){ //esc key
    var geom = drawing_feature.getGeometry();
    geom.setCoordinates(geom.getCoordinates().slice(0, -1));
    undo=true;
}
};

var drawing=false,drawing_feature=null;

lineStringdraw.on('drawstart', function(e1) {
    drawing = true;
    drawing_feature = e1.feature;
    drawing_feature.setProperties({'FID': featureID})
    var featureGeom = drawing_feature.getGeometry();
});


lineStringdraw.on('drawend', function(e2) {
    drawing = false;
    drawing_feature = null;
});
```